# Change the contents of a file based on time of the day

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, automator, shortcuts-app

On macOS, I have a Config file for a PDF viewer application, Sioyek that lets me change the background and text colours through a custom configuration combination. However, the app only allows one configuration and I would like to replace the default settings with separate configurations during the day and night. As an example, I  have the day configuration as:

**Day Configuration**

```
custom_background_color    0.92 0.89 0.83
custom_text_color    0 0 0
```

and the **Night configuration**:

```
custom_background_color    0.180 0.204 0.251
custom_text_color    0.847 0.871 0.914
```

These are stored in the app's Config file and I wish to come up with a rule that changes the file contents based on the time of the day like:

**09:00 - 17:59**
`prefs.config <- config_day`

**18:00 - 08:59**
`prefs.config <- config_night`

By the above rule, is there a way to set the contents of the Config file?

Cheers.

Comment: Use an if to choose which to select, based on he current time.

Comment: Set up two cron jobs, or two LaunchAgents, to copy the correct file into place at 09:00 and 18:00.